# Java Code: SharePoint Graph API CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217

Tags: sharepoint-online, authentication, microsoft-graph, graph-api, java

SharePoint Graph API to generate an Access token.

URL to generate access token:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token
```

URL to download a file from SharePoint:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/drive/root:/{file-path}
```

When I access the above two URLs in Postman, it works fine.

I have written a code in Java Spring Boot to automate them. Generating access token works fine I can use the generated token in postman to download a file also works fine.

But When I use the generated token in Java spring boot it does gives 401 Unauthorized and the result is:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217","innerError":{"date":"2021-10-22T06:03:42","request-id":"857c8f56-a22c-4f63-b0be-5cd66b0bf790","client-request-id":"857c8f56-a22c-4f63-b0be-5cd66b0bf790"}}}
```

but with the same access token in post man it works fine.

---

To Generate Access Token:

```
 @FeignClient(url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com", name = "sharepoint", configuration = CoreFeignConfiguration.class)
    public interface SharepointAccessTokenFeignClient {
        @RequestMapping(value = "/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/token", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_VALUE)
        @Headers("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        Map<String, Object> generateAccessToken(@PathVariable("tenant-id") String tenantId,
                                                Map<String, ?> formParams);
    }
```

To Download File:

```
@FeignClient(url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites", name = "sharepoint-graph")
public interface SharepointGraphFeignClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/{site-id}/drive/root:/{file-path}")
    Map<String, Object> getDownloadURL(@PathVariable("site-id") String siteId,
                                       @PathVariable("file-path") String filePath,
                                       @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = true) String token);
}
```

Comment: Could it be missing the bearer before the token in the header value?

Comment: bearer is added correctly